# Python Iterate Through a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary like below

```html
x_wins = {'row1_X': 'X' == x_o[0] and 'X' == x_o[1] and 'X' == x_o[2],
'row2_X' : 'X' == x_o[3] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[5],
'row3_X' : 'X' == x_o[6] and 'X' == x_o[7] and 'X' == x_o[8],
'col1_X' : 'X' == x_o[0] and 'X' == x_o[3] and 'X' == x_o[6],
'col2_X' : 'X' == x_o[1] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[7],
'col3_X' : 'X' == x_o[2] and 'X' == x_o[5] and 'X' == x_o[8],
'slant1_X' : 'X' == x_o[0] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[8],
'slant2_X' : 'X' == x_o[2] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[6]
}
```

and I want to check if any key gives True. How can I do it? Thx for help.

Comment: `any(x_wins.values())`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any of the dictionary values are true:

```py
if True in x_wins.values():
  print("Success!")
else:
  print("All False...")
```

You could also use `any` like this: `if any(x_wins.values()): ...`

If you want to get the key for which the value is True then:

```py
valid_keys = [key for key, val in x_wins.items() if val is True]
```

This will give the list of all keys that have a value of True.

Comment: But then how could you know which `key` is the successful one?

Comment: see my edit @CeliusStingher

Comment: Thanks! It;s rly simple and right idea : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to find the "True" keys if I understand correctly:

`true_keys = [x for x in x_wins if x_wins[x] == True]`

Example:

```
x_o =['X','X','X',0,0,0,'X','X','X']
x_wins = {'row1_X': 'X' == x_o[0] and 'X' == x_o[1] and 'X' == x_o[2],
'row2_X' : 'X' == x_o[3] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[5],
'row3_X' : 'X' == x_o[6] and 'X' == x_o[7] and 'X' == x_o[8],
'col1_X' : 'X' == x_o[0] and 'X' == x_o[3] and 'X' == x_o[6],
'col2_X' : 'X' == x_o[1] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[7],
'col3_X' : 'X' == x_o[2] and 'X' == x_o[5] and 'X' == x_o[8],
'slant1_X' : 'X' == x_o[0] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[8],
'slant2_X' : 'X' == x_o[2] and 'X' == x_o[4] and 'X' == x_o[6]
}
true_keys = [x for x in x_wins if x_wins[x] == True]
print(true_keys)
```

Output:

```
['row1_X', 'row3_X']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function.

The following will print `win` if any values of the x_wins dict is True :

```
if any(x_wins.values()):
    print('win!')
```